# How to create a Request to an external web service according a user in front-end behaves in magento

Tags: web-services, magento, wcf-rest

I have to integrate a web store on magento and integrate it with an external system. This system provides several functionalities, they are..
        Update stock of products
        Import products form stock
        and when a stock or product list has being updated by the front end in magento, magento has to send a notification request to the external system about the change.

first two i know there is API methods written on magento. but can you please explain me how can i achieve this task?

Thanks in advance!